# Best way to store an image from a url in php?

Tags: php

I would like to know the best way to save an image from a URL in php.

At the moment I am using

```
file_put_contents($pk, file_get_contents($PIC_URL));
```

which is not ideal. I am unable to use curl. Is there a method specifically for this?

Comment: Why is it not ideal? What are the limiting factors?

Comment: I just assumed that it was not ideal, it seemed too much like a hack

Comment: It's perfectly fine, and very clear. The only reason not to do it would be for very large files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using file_get_contents is fine, unless the file is very large. In that case, you don't really need to be holding the entire thing in memory.

For a large retrieval, you could [fopen](http://php.net/fopen) the remote file, [fread](http://php.net/fread) it, say, 32KB at a time, and [fwrite](http://php.net/fwrite) it locally in a loop until all the file has been read.

For example:

```
$fout = fopen('/tmp/verylarge.jpeg', 'w');
$fin = fopen("http://www.example.com/verylarge.jpeg", "rb");
while (!feof($fin)) {
    $buffer= fread($fin, 32*1024);
    fwrite($fout,$buffer);
}
fclose($fin);
fclose($fout);
```

(Devoid of error checking for simplicity!)

Alternatively, you could forego using the [url wrappers](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) and use a class like PEAR's [HTTP_Request](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-request.php), or roll your own HTTP client code using [fsockopen](http://php.net/fsockopen) etc. This would enable you to do efficient things like send [If-Modified-Since](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25) headers if you are maintaining a cache of remote files.

Comment: Is that far more efficient than my simple method?

Comment: It would consume less memory, since the script only ever holds 32KB of image data.

Comment: You don’t even have to buffer it.

Comment: One way or another, you're buffering it

Comment: That’s true, but you don’t buffer it redundantly.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using Paul Dixon's strategy, but replacing fopen with [fsockopen()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php). The reason is that some server configurations disallow URL access for fopen() and file_get_contents(). The setting may be found in php.ini and is called allow_url_fopen.

Comment: but as he's using file_get_contents with url wrappers, this wouldn't apply

Comment: He may be unaware of the problem. So a portable solution would drop fopen() and file_get_contents().